# tomcat jni jar location and application reload

Tags: tomcat, java-native-interface, reload

I have a servlet that makes use of a share librared via JNI and I'm having issues under tomcat9 that I didn't use to have with tomcat7.

The share libary itself is on the java (LD LIBRARY) path so is picked up by tomcat OK. However I'm having an issue with where to place the corresponding jar file.

If I place the jar file in my the webapps/WEB-INF/lib and restart tomcat everthing works. However if I reload the application using the web manager interface. The servlet no longer works and gives

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/lib/libjniast.so already loaded in another classloader

and subsequently

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

In tomcat7 it doesn't seem a problem having the jar in the webapp lib dir but I'm wondering if the behaviour has changed.

I did try moving the jar to a shared dir (/usr/share/tomcat9/lib/ ?) but it does not work (get picked up) there.

Where should the jar be located, such that reloading the app does not break things?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There was another dependent jar file. When both were placed in the /usr/share/tomcat9/lib/
things works and I can reload without issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).